# How to use map with Java?

Tags: java

The findByHourlyAggregated method should make grouping based on hours and return the Posts. The method takes the hours parameter. For example; When I access http: // localhost: 8081 / api / posts / hourly-aggregated / 2, the Posts should be listed in 2-hour segments according to the dateCreated field and return a JSON similar to the one below.

```
{
    "2020-08-11_10": [...Posts created between 10-12 o'clock on August 11...],
    "2020-08-11_12": [...Posts created between 12-14 o'clock on August 11...],
    ...
}
```

Code is here:

```
     @GetMapping("/hourly-aggregated/{hours}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> findByHourlyAggregated(@PathVariable String hours) {
        // TODO

        HashMap<Date, List<Post>> map = new HashMap<Date, List<Post>>();
        Date startDate = new Date();
        Date date = new Date();
        Timestamp endDate = null;
        Date endDate = new Date();
        List<Post> postAll = (List<Post>) findAll();
        Instant afterHours = null;
        List<Post> totalDates = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Date> allDates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        Date firstDate;
        firstDate = postAll.get(0).getDateCreated();
        for (Post p : postAll) {
            
            startDate = p.getDateCreated(); //2020-08-11 10:42:08.0 , time of incoming data
            date = new Date(firstDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(Integer.parseInt(hours))); // Tue Aug 11 12:42:08 EET 2020 
            endDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime()); // 2020-08-11 12:42:08.0, add the parameter entered with the incoming data
            
            if (firstDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime() && startDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {
                totalDates.add(p);
                
            }
            
            else {
                map.put(firstDate, totalDates);
                firstDate.setTime(endDate.getTime()); // value of new values when values in range are exhausted
                date = new Date(firstDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(Integer.parseInt(hours))); // Adds 2 hours
                endDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
                
            }
        }


        return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
        

    }
{
    "2020-08-12T02:42:08.000+03:00": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "postBody": "Post 1",
            "author": "albert",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-12T02:42:08.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "postBody": "Post 2",
            "author": "packer",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T10:45:21.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "postBody": "Post 3",
            "author": "michael",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T10:57:33.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "postBody": "Post 4",
            "author": "dwight",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T11:02:35.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "postBody": "Post 5",
            "author": "jim",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T11:52:51.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "postBody": "Post 8",
            "author": "pam",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T15:31:26.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "postBody": "Post 9",
            "author": "angela",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T16:00:00.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "postBody": "Post 11",
            "author": "oscar",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T18:21:33.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "postBody": "Post 14",
            "author": "kevin",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T22:09:56.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "postBody": "Post 16",
            "author": "creed",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T23:59:59.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "postBody": "Post 17",
            "author": "darrly",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-12T00:00:00.000+03:00"
        }
    ],
```

As output, I get all the data. What should I do?

When it enters the else part, it does the mapping and when it enters the if part again, it continues to add to the totalDates array. I want him to print what he added when he goes into the Else part and when he comes back to the if part, take the date part as a key and print it as a new arrays.
Example Output;

```
2020-08-12T10:42:08.000+03:00": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "postBody": "Post 1",
                "author": "albert",
                "dateCreated": "2020-08-12T10:42:08.000+03:00"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "postBody": "Post 2",
                "author": "packer",
                "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T10:45:21.000+03:00"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "postBody": "Post 3",
                "author": "michael",
                "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T10:57:33.000+03:00"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "postBody": "Post 4",
                "author": "dwight",
                "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T11:02:35.000+03:00"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "postBody": "Post 5",
                "author": "jim",
                "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T11:52:51.000+03:00"
            }],

2020-08-12T12:42:08.000+03:00": [
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            }], 

            ....
```

Thank you.

Comment: please update your code formatting, its unclear, especially in the first if segments

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your time range calculation logic. Let's look into that in detail :

```
P0      P1     P2      P3       P15    P16
```

| 02:42 | 10:45 | 10:57 | 11:02 |.....| 23:59 | 00:00

P0, P16 is of date 12th Aug.

P1 to P15 are all of the date 11th Aug.

Iterating over the for loop :

FirstDate : FD

EndDate  : ED

StartDate : SD

TotalDates : TD

ED=FD+2

---

P0

FD=02:42

SD=02:42

ED=04:42

TD1 = | P0 |

---

P1

FD=02:42 (12th Aug)

SD=10:45 (11th Aug)

ED=04:42

TD1 = | P0 | P1 |

---

P2

FD=02:42 (12th Aug)

SD=10:57 (11th Aug)

ED=04:42

TD1 = | P0 | P1 | P2 |

---

P3

FD=02:42 (12th Aug)

SD=11:02 (11th Aug)

ED=04:42

TD1 = | P0 | P1 | P2 | P3 |

---

```
   .
   .
```

---

P15

FD=02:42 (12th Aug)

SD=23:59 (11th Aug)

ED=04:42

TD1 = | P0 | P1 | P2 | P3 | .... | P15 |

---

P16

FD=02:42 (12th Aug)

SD=00:00 (12th Aug)

ED=04:42

TD1 = | P0 | P1 | P2 | P3 | .... | P15 | P16 |

---

The only thing I didn't understand is how you are getting the return data, I have not seen the code where you are populating the map except in one place. So I assume there could be one date where startDate is greater than the endDate.

To Fix the problem you have to make the following modifications :

```
endDate=postAll.get(0).getDateCreated();  // First in the list
for (Post p : postAll) {

        startDate = p.getDateCreated();
        date = new Date(firstDate.getTime() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(Integer.parseInt(hours))); // Adds 2 hours
        firstDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

        if (firstDate.getTime() <= startDate.getTime() && startDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {
        // Check if the firstDate is present in Map or not , if yes add into that total date or create a new list and add
            totalDates.add(p);

        } else {
          // Check the firstDate for the startDate . That can be identified by continuously reducing the firstDate with hour
          // for every firstDate check if the startDate is greater than  the firstDate, stop the serach then
          // Check if the firstDate is present in Map or not , if yes add into that total date or create a new list and add the dates
            map.put(firstDate, totalDates);

        }
    }
```